# $digest already in progress Getting this error even though not using $apply

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am getting this error in my application.

Read it in many posts that this could be due to improper usage of manual `$apply`.

But I have invoked this anywhere in my code.

Could this be due to `js` plugins such as `bootstrap/bootstrapui`, etc?

If yes then how to avoid it?

Comment: it's highly unlikely that a jQuery Plugin triggers angularJS $digest/$apply.
also, it is always good to provide code. 
Makes it quite hard to give any help without it :-(

Comment: Actually the code is very vast. Hence difficult to debug.

Comment: I agree with @AndreschSerj
It's further more very unlikely that a stable version of any plugin will cause such misbehaviour. Wihout a code snippet, this will be hard to solve.

Comment: Yes but I am getting this error only in firefox. Chrome does not show this error.

Comment: Could you look at the stack trace in Firebug to see what part of your app it is that calls $apply()?